# ASP.NET MVC webgrid post issue - Viewmodel is NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model, http-post

Here are my model classes:

```
 public class SensorTest
 {
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string SensorName { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImpactSide { get; set; }
 }

 public class SensorTestsViewModel
 {
    public List<SensorTest> SensorTestList { get; set; }

  }
```

Controller action methods:
GET:

---

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SensorTests()
    {

        SensorTestsViewModel obj = new SensorTestsViewModel();
        obj.SensorTestList = new List<SensorTest>();

        SensorTest sensortest;
        sensortest = new SensorTest();
        sensortest.SerialNo = 1;
        sensortest.SensorName = "FLAT 13 KMH";
        sensortest.TestName = "";
        obj.SensorTestList.Add(sensortest);

        sensortest = new SensorTest();
        sensortest.SerialNo = 1;
        sensortest.SensorName = "CURB IMPACT 40KMH";
        sensortest.TestName = "";
        obj.SensorTestList.Add(sensortest);

        return View(obj);
    }
```

POST:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("SensorTests")]
    public ActionResult SensorTests_Post(SensorTestsViewModel sensortests)
    {
        //SensorTestsViewModel model = new SensorTestsViewModel();
        //UpdateModel(model);

        return View(sensortests);
    }
```

View code:

```
@model  Safety.Models.SensorTestsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SensorTests", "Safety"))
{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.SensorTestList, canSort: false, canPage:   false);
int rowNum = 0;
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml(columns:
        grid.Columns
        (
            grid.Column("SerialNo", format: item => rowNum = rowNum + 1),
             grid.Column("SensorName"),
            grid.Column("TestName", format: (item) =>    Html.TextBox("TestName[" + (rowNum - 1).ToString() + "].TestName", (object)item.TestName))

        ), mode: WebGridPagerModes.Numeric)
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

See the Viewmodel is null during POST. I have tried UpdateModel as well. My requirement is I need to post whole viewmodel data to controller and do the necessary actions from there. Not sure what I am missing? Can someone Please suggest?

Comment: I do not think you can post a WebGrid in this way, can you show what html is rendered from this view?

Comment: Adding below info to understand my requirement. TestName text box -- user can enter any test name. I will be adding autocomplete to select a test. I need the Testnames along with SerialNo and Sensorname for all the rows in webgrid in my controller to perform necessary operations.

Comment: I just wanted to see what name/id your textbox has in the end, these are important if you want to bind to a model.

Comment: <form action="/Safety/SensorTests" method="post">    <div>
            <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
SerialNo            </th>
            <th scope="col">
SensorName            </th>
            <th scope="col">
TestName            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

Comment: <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>FLAT 13 KMH</td>
            <td><input id="TestName_0__TestName" name="TestName[0].TestName" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>CURB IMPACT 40KMH</td>
            <td><input id="TestName_1__TestName" name="TestName[1].TestName" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at this example: [post items of webgrid asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113839/post-items-of-webgrid-asp-net-mvc3)

**Try making the textbox name like this:** "SensorTestList[someIndexHere].SensorName"